# Flutter TextFormField validator does not work?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

Hi fellas Im new in Flutter/Dart Programming. Im trying to build an app that includes dynamic TextFormField. Validator does not returning text in the screen. Could you give me an explanation so i could build my app in the correct way.

```
import 'package:camework/global/styles.dart';
import 'package:camework/repos/surveyRepo/surveyRepo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../../../global/appLocatizations.dart';


class DefaultQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  const DefaultQuestion({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DefaultQuestion> createState() => _DefaultQuestionState();
}

class _DefaultQuestionState extends State<DefaultQuestion> {
  TextEditingController surveyTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SurveyRepo surveyRepo = Provider.of<SurveyRepo>(context);
    var questionType = surveyRepo.surveyQuestion!.questionType!.mask!;
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: ProjectStyles.textFieldDecoration(null, null, null),
      keyboardType: keyboardType(questionType),
      inputFormatters: [inputFormat(questionType)],
      autofocus: true,
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        if (value != null && value != "") {
          setState(() {
            surveyTextController.text = value;
            surveyRepo.textQuestionTrigger(value);
          });
        }
      },
      key: _formKey,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value != null) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {

`THIS IS NOT WORKING`

            return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("thisFieldCannotBeEmpty");
          }
        }
      },
      controller: surveyTextController,
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: If it never goes into your function, you might want to add the `autovalidationMode` property to your field.

Else, use `print(value)` at the begging of your function to know why it doesn't go in your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_formKey` is used for the key of `Form` Widget. Not for the `TextFormField`.

see example from documentation : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

```
return Form(
  key: _formKey, // <= Use here
  child: TextFormField(
    // rest of property
    //...
    validator : (val) {
     // your  function for validation
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a validator using the validator property.

Like that

TextFormField(
validator: EmailValidator(errorText: 'enter a valid email address')
);